# set channel for LoggingHandler

Tags: spring-integration, spring-xd

I was writing my own unit test for my springxd module, (however, I didn't plan to use `xd.test` and `xd.dirt`).

This is a processor module, what I did for the test are:

configure the context:

```
ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("config/spring-module.xml");
```

get the `input` `DirectChannl` and `send(Message)`

```
input = ctx.getBean("input", DirectChannel.class);

input.send(msg);
```

but for a `DirectChannel`, I have to provide it a `subscriber`, so I decided to write a `LoggingHandler` `Bean` to the `ouput` `DirectChannel`, this is it:

```
@Bean
public LoggingHandler outputLogging(){
    LoggingHandler lh = new LoggingHandler("INFO");
    lh.setLoggerName("output-logging");
    lh.setShouldLogFullMessage(true);
    return lh;
}
```

But my problem is: I need the `loggingHandler` to be the subscriber of the `output` channel. So I have to somehow configure it with `output`. I got a solution like:

```
@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "output")
public LoggingHandler outputLogging(){
    LoggingHandler lh = new LoggingHandler("INFO");
    lh.setLoggerName("output-logging");
    lh.setShouldLogFullMessage(true);
    return lh;
}
```

But however there was still an `Exception` for:

```
org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@76b0bfab.output'.; nested exception is org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:81)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:442)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:392)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:115)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:45)
at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:105)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:231)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.produceOutput(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:154)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageProducingHandler.sendOutputs(AbstractMessageProducingHandler.java:102)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:105)
at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:127)
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:116)
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:147)
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:120)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:442)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:392)
at com.example.test.TestAll.allTest(TestAll.java:58)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:153)
at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:120)
at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
... 42 more
```

So, my question is:

Do I need to configure the module either with `xml` or with `annotation`, I can't use them both?

If I can, is there a solution not using the `@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "output")`, it looks like :

```
<int:service-activator input-channel="input" method="trans" output-channel="output">
    <bean class="com.example.LoggingHandler" init-method="init" destroy-method="destroy">
...
    </bean>
</int:service-activator>
```

which actually I didn't need the service-activator.

Thanks!

[updated]

```
@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
public class TestAll {

    ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx;
    DirectChannel input;
    DirectChannel output;
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(TestAll.class);
    //you have to configure this before you run, point this to the file path in the main/resources
    String folderPath = "C:\\path\\to\\samples";

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("config/spring-module.xml");
        input = ctx.getBean("input", DirectChannel.class);
        output = ctx.getBean("output", DirectChannel.class);
        logger.setLevel(Level.ALL);
        //ctx.addBeanFactoryPostProcessor(beanFactoryPostProcessor);
    }

    @Test
    public void allTest(){
        Message<?> msg = composeMsg();
        input.send(msg);
        logger.debug(output.isLoggingEnabled());
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "output")
    public LoggingHandler outputLogging(){
        LoggingHandler lh = new LoggingHandler("INFO");
        lh.setLoggerName("output-logging");
        lh.setShouldLogFullMessage(true);
        return lh;
    }

    public Message<?> composeMsg(){
   ...
        return MessageBuilder.withPayload(msgPayload).copyHeaders(msgHeader).build();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown(){
        ctx.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is test-case I think you go right way just to import the real module config and provide some testing harness to make it working and finish the task.

And I even think that you go right way with that `@ServiceActivator` configuration.

Only the problem that you are missing there `@EnableIntegration` alongside with the `@Configuration`.

On the other hand, I'd better make `@BridgeFrom("output")` on the `QueueChannel` `@Bean` to `assert` the processor results in the end of test. 
But you need `@EnableIntegration` anyway.

**UPDATE**

OK. Thank you for the updated code. Now I see. The problem that your `TestAll` `@Configuration` class isn't registered with the `ApplicationContext`. Therefore nobody is going to process `@EnableIntegration` and register your `LoggingHandler` `@Bean` and so on.

Try this one:

```
@ContextConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@DirtiesContext
public class TestAll {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("input")
    private MessageChannel inputChannel;

    @Autowired
    private PollableChannel resultChannel;

    @Test
    public void allTest(){
        Message<?> msg = composeMsg();
        input.send(msg);
        Message<?> result = resultChannel.receive(10000);
        assertNotNull(result);
        // Other asserts
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableIntegration
    @ImportResource("classpath:config/spring-module.xml")
    public static class ContextConfiguration {

        @BridgeFrom("output")
        public PollableChannel resultChannel() {
             return new QueueChannel();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks Artern, I think I will try the `@BridgeForm`. But actually, I have both `@EnableIntegration` and `@Configuration` annotated to my test class. I am also thinking about to add  `bean` in runtime. any way, thanks for your work. and I update the question with my code, hope it would help you to find what is wrong with my code.